# Assigning commands to str does not work

Tags: pdftex, expl3, latex3, strings

I want to assign the values of other commands (like `\nobreakspace`) to a string to be able to use these later.

Assigning does not seem to work as it is taking the commands literaly...

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% =====================================
% correct number displaying

\usepackage[mode=text, reset-text-series = false, separate-uncertainty, group-digits=integer, group-minimum-digits = 4]{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator = {\,}, input-decimal-markers={,.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \g__eur_length_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\setcurrencyformat}{m}
{
    \str_gset:Nn \g__eur_length_str { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EUR}{om}
{
    \currency_print_value:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { € }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\currency}{om}
{
    \currency_print_value:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { }
}


\cs_new_protected:Nn \currency_print_value:nnn
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {% no optional argument
        \currency_print:Vnn \g__eur_length_str { #2 } { #3 }
    }
    {% optional argument present
        \currency_print:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
    }
}

\str_new:N \l__currency_temp_str

\cs_new_protected:Nn \currency_print:nnn
{
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {#3} { }
    { % empty
        \str_set:Nn \l__currency_temp_str {}
    }
    { % not empty
        \str_set:Nn \l__currency_temp_str { \nobreakspace \unit{#3} }
    }
    
    \str_show:N \l__currency_temp_str
    
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
    {
        { full }    { \num[group-separator = {.}, minimum-decimal-digits = 2]{#2} \str_use:N \l__currency_temp_str }
        { standard }{ \num[group-separator = {.}, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]{#2} \str_use:N \l__currency_temp_str }     
        { min }     { \num[group-separator = {.}, round-mode = places, round-precision = 0]{#2} \str_use:N \l__currency_temp_str }
        { noseperator }  { #2 } %\nobreakspace \unit{#3} }
}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \currency_print:nnn { V }

\setcurrencyformat{full}

\ExplSyntaxOff


% =====================================
% calculation

\RequirePackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
    
    \currency[noseparator]{123.45678} (currency[noseparator])
    
    \EUR{456.7890} (EUR)

    
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Is `\str_set:nn \l_temp_str { \nobreakspace \unit{#3} }` not correct? I also tried `\str_set:nV \l_temp_str { \nobreakspace \unit{#3} }` to take the value of the commands which did not work either...

Comment: `str` is definitely the wrong variable type. Use `tl`.

Comment: `str` is like `\string`  no csname tokens

Comment: It does work with `tl`, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `str` datatype matches the result of primitives such as `\string`, `\detokenize`, ...  All character tokens of catcode 12 (other) except space which is catcode 10.

So you can not store a csname token such as `\unit` in a `str`

Use the `tl` (token list) datatype.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helped quite a lot!